# My htaccess is not having effect when i serve to a another port on XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I am having an issue please. I have a project in

`C:\xampp\htdocs\woski`.

The htacess works when i access it on the browser via

`localhost/woski`

but the project needs its separate port to function properly.

I run command below in terminal

`php -S localhost:3122`

I then access the project on the browser via

`localhost:3122`

The PROBLEM is that the `htaccess` here doesn't have effect on this separate port 3122.

Everything seems to be working fine except the `.htaccess` having effect on the project when ran on this port.

How can I solve this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` is an Apache configuration file.  The PHP built-in web server is not a full fledged Apache web server.

To use advanced features that Apache provides, you have to install Apache, install PHP, add PHP modules into Apache, then use .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks alot, I figured it out now . This was helpful

Comment: Do not hesitate to accept the answer, with the check box on the left :-)